# Facing issue on Linux - PC with 2 IP address from same subnet

Tags: linux

I am new in Linux networking programming. I am facing issue on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit platform (This is also observed on Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, Ubuntu 16.04, 32bit) below are the details,

Setup:
1. The machine is having two LAN interfaces(IP address) with same subnet(e.g eth0: 172.16.0.165(default ip address) and eth1: 172.16.0.105)
2. Socket is bind with 'SO_BROADCAST' socket option and 'INADDR_ANY' address
3. UDP connection is used for communication

Issue:
When Unicast (request to IP address 172.16.0.105) or broadcast (request to 172.16.255.255) requests are received to application(which is running on 172.16.0.105), response is expected from same IP address(i.e 172.16.0.105) but response is received from default IP address(i.e 172.16.0.165)

Can u please someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Two interfaces on the same broadcasting network, they both will try to answer your broadcast request. You can configure the "iptables" on Linux how to allow and deny the packet based on the source and destination.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response

Comment: I have tried configuration of "iptables" on Linux. but i didn't get appropriate result. it will be grateful if you share any example related to "iptables" configuration